# How to highlight multiple elements under the overlap page

Tags: css, html5-canvas

I want to highlight multiple elements under the overlap page, the expected result will be like this:

[image: expected_highlighted_pic]

I have tried to increase the `z-index` of this element (I have tried this, but I met some issues to cause `z-index` not to work), can we use canvas to do it?
Are there any detailed steps about it?

Comment: If you want to show something like tour, You can try with bootstrap tour :http://bootstraptour.com/api/

Comment: Please be more clear about what your goal is. The purpose of your screenshot is vague, I don't know if the question is asking how to handle highlight logic and/or styling and how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch off the pointer-events of your overlapping element: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

(also you may switch it off when the cursor is over the circle)